# How to clone an object with behavior in as3

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, clone

I know that I can clone an object simply by setting a new object to the .clone() of the first object, but cloning merely copies all the data at the time of the cloning and transfers it to a new object. I want to make one object copy the behavior of another object after cloning, so that changes made to one are made to both without having to deal with the coding of both.

I do not want to

1. Put a clone function in a frameEnter Event (the complex object will destroy performance).
2. Run all the code for one object on both objects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: _"so that changes made to one are made to both"_ - Just thought I would double check, how familiar are you with AS3? Are you familiar with how references work?

Comment: This is my first class with AS3, but i think I know what references are. You use references when you set one object equal to another, but as an address, so if you change one you change the other. But I need to be able both to the stage separately, and since the reference is still technically the original object, just under a different variable name that wouldn't work unless I'm looking at it the wrong way.

Comment: Have you looked into class definitions? What you're describing sounds like a perfect use case for making a custom class, then creating 2 separate instances of that class.

Comment: I have a class, but is my only option to apply every line of code to the first object to the second or is there a way to dynamically clone the object?